# Automatically open a popup on load with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a page with ASP.net MVC 5 with Bootstrap in that displays a table of many records. I have a popup that open when I click on a button that is located on each row, basically some CRUD. This works fine.

What I would like to do now is when a user enter a specific URL (like site/Proof/LoadSpecific/342) to open the page as usual, but also show the modal as if I clicked on a specific button.

I am faily new to MVC, JQuery and web in general. How would I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: please post the code for your modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap modals you can use the following functions (assuming you have the bootstrap js and jquery scripts included as well)

assuming `myModal` is the `id` of your modal element:

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle'); //toggles the shown/hidden state of the modal
$('#myModal').modal('show');  //shows the modal
$('#myModal').modal('hide');  //hides the modal
```

so you would include a script on your page that shows the bootstrap modal on load such as the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Here's a [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/) to the bootstrap 3.3 documentation which has a good deal more information on these components and how you can use them.